# How do I write dynamic SQL from a temp table to update each employee record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have the following temp table (`#updates`):

```
userid    newvalue
------------------
031233    A
467763    B
656532    C
```

I need to update the user table for each recordset:

```
update tbl.users set foo = 'A' where id = '031233';
update tbl.users set foo = 'B' where id = '467763';
update tbl.users set foo = 'C' where id = '656532';
```

AFAIK, I need dynamic SQL to read the `#updates` table and perform the updates:

```
declare @cnt int;
declare @id int = 1;

select @cnt = count(1) from #updates; -- 3

while @id <= @cnt
    begin
        select @id;
        select @sql = N'update tbl.users set foo = ' + ?? + 'where id = ' + ??;
        exec sp_executesql @sql;
        select @id = @id + 1;
    end
;
```

Obviously, this is not working but even after a few hours of googling and trying, this is the best I can do.

Can anyone help me and tell me how I properly loop through the temp table?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop. This can be done with a `join`.

```
update u
set foo = upd.newvalue
from tbl.users u
join #updates upd on u.id = upd.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to loop through a table you need a `CURSOR`.  You can find documentation for them [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx).  In your example your loop would look something like

```
Declare c CURSOR Local Fast_Forward For
  Select userid, newvalue from #updates

  Open c
    Declare @userid varchar(10), @newvalue varchar(5)

    Fetch Next From c Into @userid, @newvalue
    While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin
      select @sql = N'update tbl.users set foo = ' + @newvalue + 'where id = ' + @userid;
      exec sp_executesql @sql;

      Fetch Next From c Into @userid, @newvalue
    End

  Close c

Deallocate c
```

As you can see, the setup for a cursor is quite verbose and ugly.  Cursors are typically frowned upon as well and you should only use them if you really need to.  In your case you don't.  You can just join your temp table to your base table and update it that way

```
Update u Set 
  foo = t.newvalue
From tbl.Users u 
  Join #updates t On t.userid = u.id
```

This is much more performant and easier to read

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to loop, a query is fine.
Since no one proposed a MERGE I do:

```
MERGE INTO tbl.users
   USING #updates
      ON tbl.users.id = #updates.userid 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET foo = #updates.newvalue
```

SQL server version should be >= 2008 I think